# Python - Removing the whitespace before the output

Tags: python, whitespace

I'm fairly new to Python..
I was wondering how do i remove the whitespace that comes right before the output..

```
height = input("Please enter the tree height : ")
height1 = height
trunk = height/3
spacevar = str(" ")
for i in range(0,height):
    print spacevar*(height)+"*"*(((i+1)*2)-1)
    height = height-1
for p in range (0,trunk):
    print spacevar*height1+"*"
```

the output is

```
Please enter the tree height : 5
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
=*********
     *
```

The text slot marked with = is the "whitespace" i need to remove..
Thanks guys !

Comment: please post the code as well.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html  (string operations like strip)

Comment: If you want to replace just 1 whitespace then simply use `line[1:]` for every line, or `replace('\n ', '\n')`. If you want to replace all the whitespace use `*strip` methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - paint a tree HW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111544/python-paint-a-tree-hw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got what you mean here:

```
height = input("Please enter the tree height : ")
height1 = height
trunk = height/3
spacevar = str(" ")

for i in range(0,height):
    print spacevar*(height-1)+"*"*(((i+1)*2)-1)
    height = height-1
for p in range (0,trunk):
    print spacevar*(height1-1)+"*"
```

I just replaces the (height) and height1 operands to -1. Seems to have done the trick for me in the example. If this is not what you meant please just let me know.

Comment: Thanks alot mate, that fixed it ! 
Highly appriciated ;)!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are storing each line in an string, you can use the strip method.

Example Usage:

```
a = "  ****  "
a.strip()   //Will Produce a string of "****"
a.lstrip()  //Will Produce a string of "****  "
a.rstrip()  //Will Produce a string of "  ****"
```

Comment: As you can see in the code, it is not an in-string space.. just the output line first "text slot" space i need to remove

Comment: @user1792223 Try this: `print str(spacevar*(height)+"*"*(((i+1)*2)-1)).lstrip()` in your code.

Comment: It killed the spaces as a whole.. which whom i needed for the tree to be painted :P

Comment: You can use if loop to do lstrip at the required line you want.